# How do i get a wet bicarbonate of soda stain out of my carpet?

Tags: cleaning, carpet, stain

I had a stain on my carpet, the professional came round tried to remove it and later it turned pink, he told me to add bicarbonate of soda watered down 1/5, the pink faded but not completely he said to put more bicarb on which i did and it worked on the stain (not completely but enough to live with)however, the surrounding edge where the bicarb had flooded onto it turned a darker shade of my carpet and now i have a massive stain of bicarb on the carpet.It looks worse than the original stain. How do I get rid of the bicarb stain now?

Comment: Are you sure that's a stain rather than just a cleaner area?

Comment: ...or a still-damp area?

Comment: Bicarb and most carbonates are white. Perhaps your water leached something dark from the carpet padding. A steam clean would probably get it, but I'd try a damp, not wet, sponge first. Rinse the sponge plenty of times, as it'll be picking up lots of carbonates.

Comment: Maybe try vinegar?

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

Maybe.

You might get lucky but sometimes a series of chemical processes ends up fixing the stain permanently. A research chemist and a lot of time and money might fix it but sometimes you have to consider alternatives.

Not too long ago, a plumber left a stain on a carpet. I went through a variety of products and services to try an remove it. In the end it was worse than it was before I started.

I paid a carpet fitter to replace the carpet.

Comment: Oxalic acid is good for iron stains. I don't think there's a consumer available reducing agent on the market now, like dithionite or metabixufite,  but those would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the dark ring around the spot is not a stain but dirt under the carpet that has gotten wet and wicked a bit into the carpet.

Use a carpet cleaner machine on the area; you might need multiple passes, but if the carpet cleaner machine is worth anything, it will get it done in fairly quick order.

Comment: You'll probably need to clean the whole carpet or you'll end up with a clean spot.